# Loading a Union SQL View into access table

Tags: sql, ms-access, view, union

I'm trying to create an access table (with a Primary key) that loads in the data from a Union SQL view.

Im hoping there is a way of achieving this? Ive tried an append and create table queries which copies the data but still no primary key.

I've created a blank table with the fields i want but cant think how to import the fields from the view into it?

Am i better off loading the view into excel?

Any tips would be great!

thanks

Comment: Hi, does the view have data from multiple tables?  Are you intending on  updating the data?  If you're not going to edit the data then view why don't you simply use the view as the table rather than creating a new table.

Comment: Hi There, Yep it has multiple tables. Nope another source updates the tables. Ive tried using the View as a table but there is no way of defining a primary key and all the fields are set to short text.

Comment: Cool, so in your view use the NewID() function.

here's a link:  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190348.aspx

The NewId will create a rowID for you.

Comment: That sounds perfect will i have to add it onto each line of my union?

Comment: SELECT     PLSupplierAccountID AS SageAccountID, SupplierAccountNumber AS AccountNumber, 
                      SupplierAccountName AS AccountName, 'RWL' AS Company
FROM         Roth.dbo.PLSupplierAccount
UNION ALL
SELECT   PLSupplierAccountID AS SageAccountID, SupplierAccountNumber AS AccountNumber, 
                      SupplierAccountName AS AccountName, 'FAH' AS Company
FROM         FAH.dbo.PLSupplierAccount
UNION ALL
SELECT     PLSupplierAccountID AS SageAccountID, SupplierAccountNumber AS AccountNumber, 
                      SupplierAccountName AS AccountName, 'RFG' AS

Comment: cool, good luck, remember to upvote the comment :)

Comment: Does the New ID() select random numbers? is there a way of using 1,2,3,4 etc...?

Comment: I didn't think it did.  The only other way is to do it like this:  Create View [MyView] as

SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER( ORDER BY col1 ) AS id, col1, col2, col3
FROM(
    Select col1, col2, col3 From Table1
    Union All
    Select col1, col2, col3 From Table2 ) AS MyResults
GO

Comment: Unfortunately it did, have you got any tips how i can adapt my code to incorporate the above i'm struggling to get it to run!

Comment: did you see my last example?  create a view using row_number over etc etc.

Comment: I did, do i need to create a new view and refer to my old view? or add the code into my existing?

Comment: create a new view in that format, where it says from()  you can put you select statements in there, as long as the columns after the as match what you're selecting

Comment: I tried the following

Comment: Create View [dbo.zzAllPLSuppliers] as SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER( ORDER BY col1 ) AS id, col1, col2, col3, col4  FROM( Select  PLSupplierAccountID AS AccountID, SupplierAccountNumber AS AccountNumber,SupplierAccountName AS AccountName, 'RWL' AS Company From Roth.dbo.PLSupplierAccount Union All 
Select PLSupplierAccountID AS AccountID, SupplierAccountNumber AS AccountNumber,SupplierAccountName AS AccountName, 'FAH' AS Company From  FAH.dbo.PLSupplierAccount) AS MyResults Go

Comment: but it says incorrect syntax near GO?

Comment: remove go, and also the col1, col2 etc should be AccountID, AccountNumber etc...

Comment: Wait, are you using Access or Sql-Server? Because `NewID()` is not an access function. Nor does Access support window functions like `Row_Number()`

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are trying to turn this query into a table because the query takes a long time to run and the data don't change often. In which case this is fine. Otherwise you should really be using your query. And if having a PK is a problem (which it shouldn't be because you can't edit a union query) then you should explain more about what you are trying to do.

Anyway, to turn your query into a table you need to make a table with the columns in your query and add one more column which is an `AutoNumber` column. This is your PK. Then create your append query like normal. Don't append anything to the `AutoNumber` column, it will automatically populate itself when a new row is added.